# React useCallback hook, not receiving updated dependency state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, dom-events

Below is my simplified version of the problem I'm trying to solve.

Anyone know why my `handleKeydown` method is not receiving the updated `activeTab` state variable?  I though that because I added `activeTab` as a dependency, the callback would always receive the updated value.  However, that does not seem to be the case.

The callback is called, as expected, every time a key is pressed; However, `activeTab` is always `null`, the initial value. Any help is appreciated!

(I've included both a code snippet as well as a jsfiddle link (because the snippet does not seem to be rendering for some reason. The jsfiddle at least renders lol).)

https://jsfiddle.net/Tom904/98veow5b/4/

```js
const Tabs = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = React.useState(null);
  
  
  const handleKeydown = React.useCallback(event => {
    console.log(activeTab);
    // if a user hits the escape key while a tab is active...
    if (event.key === 'Escape' && activeTab) {
      setActiveTab(null);
    }
  }, [activeTab]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setActiveTab('1')}>
         1
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setActiveTab('2')}>
         2
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setActiveTab('3')}>
         3
      </button>
      <div>
        Active tab: {activeTab || 'None'}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
  
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tabs/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `handleKeydown` function is updated on every change of `activeTab`. However the `useEffect` in which you bind the function to the `keydown` event is only called on mount. So although the function is recreated, the original instance, with the initial value of `activeTab`, is called by the event handler.

The `useCallback` here is redundant, and you can also use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) form of `useState` to avoid the `activeTab` dependancy:

```js
const Tabs = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeydown = event => {      
      setActiveTab(activeTab => event.key === 'Escape' && activeTab ? null : activeTab);
    };
  
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setActiveTab('1')}>
         1
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setActiveTab('2')}>
         2
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setActiveTab('3')}>
         3
      </button>
      <div>
        Active tab: {activeTab || 'None'}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
  
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tabs/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, wasn't having the same problem and I know my lifecycles really well but this question (and answer) helped me spot a bug in my code :D